# Reference Request: Cubic and Biquadratic Reciprocity Law

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, quadratic-reciprocity, cubic-reciprocity

I want to read about the Cubic and Biquadratic Reciprocity Laws after learning the Quadratic Reciprocity Law. I already know about Franz Lemmermeyer's book "Reciprocity Laws", but I think this is a bit too advanced for me. Do you know any introductionary material?

Comment: You could try Ireland and Rosen's *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory*: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Classical-Introduction-Modern-Number-Theory/dp/038797329X/

Comment: cox's book primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$